# formatting numbers to currencies using setNumberFormat

Tags: google-apps-script, numbers, currency

I know iin apps script that if I have a column with a small number in euro format like 3 or 3,45 I can use

```
 var column = sheet3.getRange("J2:J")
 column.setNumberFormat("[$€]#,##0.00");
```

to change the number into €3.00 or €3.45

But I have no idea how I can change larger numbers like 1.995,95€ (the european way of writing it) into €1,999.95 (the right way!)

This is at least partly because I don't really understand what's going on here: setNumberFormat("[$€]#,##0.00"), I just use it.

I've looked all over google and youtube but I can't find anything about this so I'm really hoping someone can explain how it works to me and also explain how to do the Euro change above.

Please help!

Comment: Because it's easy, I've just changed "." into "" and "," into "." then added a € on the front.

I really want to understand this #,##0.00 notation though, please.

Answer (score 1):

**Recommendation:**

You would need to clean the numbers before you can format them to your desired currency. With that being said, you may refer to this sample code below to clean the numbers on your sheet (`J2:J`), then re-post the numbers back to your sheet on Column J, and then format them:

**Code**:

```
 function formatNumbers() {
  var sheet3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var column = sheet3.getRange("J2:J");
  var num = [];
  var count = 0;
  column.getValues().forEach(res => {//clean the numbers from 'J2:J' removes any uncessary characters and leave only number with commas and dots
    if(res != ''){
      num[count++] = res.toString().replace(/[^\d.,-]/g,'').replace(',','.');
    }
  });
  for(var x=0; x<num.length;x++){//check if there are any numbers with 3 sections, such as [1].[995],[95]
    var cont = num[x].split('.');
    if(cont.length>=3){
      var newNum = cont[0]+','+cont[1]+'.'+cont[2]; // corrects the order of comma and dot on the number
      num[x] = newNum;
    }
    sheet3.getRange(2+x,10).setValue(num[x]); //getRange(2,10) is equivalent to 'J2:J'. 2 is row of column 10 (or column J)
  }
  sheet3.getRange("J2:J").setNumberFormat("[$€]#,##0.00");
}
```

Here's a sample sheet:

[image]

After running the code, this will be the result:

[image]

**Additional Info:**

As per the notation #,##0.00, you can refer to the [Number format examples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_examples) for more information. Basically, you're using the #,##0.00 notation because you wanted to make sure the first section of the number (#,##) is in decimal format and then the last section, you use 0.00 because you want to include whole numbers with .00 (e.g. 3 to 3.00).

Comment: Ah very interesting. I had considered using split and cleaning the numbers before formatting - which is why in the end I used 

strr = number
strr = replace "." with "," 
strr = replace "," with "."

I like your version better.

The only remaining question is how do the "[$€]#.##0.00" formatting codes work? I've read the number format examples but they don't really explain. Or, maybe I'm asking too much of them? I thought I could use them *on their own* to format numbers without having to use any pre processing. If that isn't the case maybe I did understand them after all!

Comment: I'm unable to find a publicly available documentation that explains how this code works. However, on my further research, "[$€]#.##0.00" is one of the patterns (http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/numbers-currency/number-patterns) to be used by the .setNumberFormat() method to format numbers. For example, if the number has unknown formats like 2,1€, 2,1 or 1.995,67, it won't be formatted to "[$€]#.##0.00" as the .setNumberFormat() method can only read identifiable numbers such as 2.1€, 2.1 or 1,995.67.